# snmpwalk to ipv6 address timeout

Tags: ipv6, snmp, net-snmp

Snmpwalk is failing. I don't know why. I have a host configured with a global
ipv6 address. Snmpd is listening on ipv6.

```
netstat -l|grep snmp
udp6       0      0 [::]:snmp               [::]:*
udp6       0      0 [::]:snmp-trap          [::]:*
```

Snmpwalk, on the same host, is failing.

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c public udp6:[::1] system
Timeout: No Response from udp6:[::1]
```

What could the problem be?

snmpd.conf

```
agentAddress  udp6:161
syslocation  home
syscontact  neil@example.com
rocommunity  public 
disk  / 5000kB
```

snmpd shows a connection in syslog.

```
Jul 16 22:25:41 scope snmpd[11066]: Connection from UDP/IPv6: [2604:xxxx:100:8111::3]:53063
Jul 16 22:25:42 scope snmpd[11066]: Connection from UDP/IPv6: [2604:xxxx:100:8111::3]:53063
Jul 16 22:25:43 scope snmpd[11066]: Connection from UDP/IPv6: [2604:xxxx:100:8111::3]:53063
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Access control is configured per transport.  Try replacing

```
rocommunity public
```

with

```
rocommunity6 public
```

Comment: Exactly the right answer. `rocommunity6` defines the community string for the IPv6 transport.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
com2sec6 local     ::1                  public
```

to your `/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf` file.